# What format does Facebook api return as "birthday"

Tags: facebook, facebook-permissions

According to Facebook docs requesting birthday data is done by requesting **user_birthday** permission set and then the birthday string is stored under **birthday** in the return array.

What format does it return in, and does the format vary according to users setting?

Formats that I would predict

```
1990-05-22 // standard
05.22.1990 // USA reverse format
22.05 // User hid birth year
1990 // Getting only birth year without a date
NULL // User hid entire birthday
```

For me right now is important to determine whether Facebook gives one standard format of **birthday** value or its format depends on users birthday settings?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The birthday returned by the facebook is a **string** of the format: `MM/DD/YYYY`.

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/).

Comment: According to new Graph API

The person's birthday. This is a fixed format string, like MM/DD/YYYY. However, people can control who can see the year they were born separately from the month and day so this string can be only the year (YYYY) or the month + day (MM/DD)